# Task-based vs task-positive networks

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, neuroimaging

Do the terms "task-*positive* network" and "task-*based* network" refer to the same thing, such as the Fronto-Parietal Control Network (FPCN), as distinct from the task-negative networks such as the Default Mode Network (DMN); or do the terms refer to two different types of brain networks?

The question arose to me after having read Fischmeister et al. 2016 ("Self-similarity and recursion as default modes in human cognition"), a paper that contrasts the roles of the DMN and FPCN, each seen as archtypes of the task-negative and task-positive (task-based??) networks respectively. However, there are other papers that also seem to employ the two terms interchangeably, while yet others appear to use only one or another - which is why I thought the question might be worth raising in this forum.